# How to turn on regular expressions in ADT Bundle for Linux?

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

It doesn't seem to work. I pressed `Ctrl + F`, typed `^Log$` and nothing was found although I had a line contains `Log` and nothing more. Why? Do I need any extra plugins?

My IDE is ADT Bundle for Linux (build: v21.1.0-569685).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you check for any whitespace around `Log`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, thank you. I forgot about four white spaces that started any line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^[ \t]*Log[ \t]*$
```

to account for potential tabs and spaces around your string.

(I wouldn't use `^\s*Log\s*$`, by the way, because `\s` also matches newlines)